# Most efficient way of drawing a large array of rectangles

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a general question.

I am currently building a silverlight application that requires the generation of a large amount of rectangle objects. An example scenario would be 25 x 25 x 128 (stored inside a rectangle[,,]). The rectangles appearance can change depending on the contents of an int array of the same size.

The rectangles are then drawn onto a canvas. The current layer can be changed so that you get a different group of rectangles (controlled by the "z" axis of the multidimensional array)

This might seem obvious so I apologise in advance if that's the case. But is it more efficient to generate all these rectangles inside a large rectangle[,,] in one operation or to generate each layer into a rectangle[,] as the user requests it?

Comment: Well, if you got a memory issue (or rendering) then I would aim for a solution where the application create those rectangles for every z-zayer that is near the current one (eg. -/+ 3, so the user can scroll/change them quite fast if its not from TOP->DOWN in a very limited time amount) That will only work of course, when the user changes the z-layers one by one and not from 70 to ->150 in one step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it more efficient to generate all these rectangles inside a large rectangle[,,] in one operation or to generate each layer into a rectangle[,] as the user requests it?

That totally depends. You can do the benchmarking of that because you are building the application, we don't know what you do before and after and what you want to store.

I'd say: create a `Layer` class that holds its own `Rectangle[,]` reference, so you'll have all responsibilities in one place, then iterate through a `List<Layer>`. You can then store, retreive and edit individual layers while the other rectangles remain untouched.

This way you can also easily load one layer if required.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution, I'll have at this. Thanks CodeCaster!